# For what values of x does the graph of f (x) have a horizontal tangent? $f(x) = 3x^3 + 9x^2 + 2x + 8$

Tags: calculus

I am having a hard time understanding where -1 came in this quadratic equation. I am stuck. I plugged in values from $ax^2+bx+c=0$ into the quadratic equation.

What do i do form there?:

1) Can I cancel out the $18$ in the denominator and the 18 located out side the radical?
2) Where do I go from there. I plugged the x values I got, $x= 11,-13$ but those are not correct.
3) How did they get $-1.816$?  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=\displaystyle\frac{-18\pm\sqrt{216}}{18}=-\frac{18}{18}\pm\frac{\sqrt{216}}{18}=-1\pm\frac{\sqrt{216}}{18}\approx-1\pm0.816.....$

If the tangent is horizontal then the slope is $0$, so solve for which $x$ does $f'(x)=0$?

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of the given function

$f(x) = 3x^3 + 9x^2 + 2x + 8$

is

$f'(x) = 9x^2+18x+2$.

Now do $f'(x) = 0$

and find out the root to end up with your right solution.

You were taking derivative as $f'(x) = 9x^2+18x+3$ which is false.

Comment: First question. Why has the -18 disappeared and how?

Comment: The derivative of a constant is $0$